# What is correct way to handle fetch response

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I have following code which I using for handling Magento 2 REST API.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(uri, { method, headers, body: JSON.stringify(data) })
        .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(responseData => {
          resolve(responseData);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
```

And I want to add response status checking, so I've started like this

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(uri, { method, headers, body: JSON.stringify(data) })
        .then(response => {
          return {
            data: response.json(),
            ok: response.ok,
            status: response.statusText
          };
        })
        .then(responseResult => {
          if (responseResult.ok) {
            resolve(responseResult.data);
          } else {
            const error = responseResult.status || responseResult.data.message;
            reject(error);
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
```

Magento keeps error text inside `data.message`, but `response.json()` return me a `Promise` instead of `data`.

What is a correct way to handle this case?

UPDATE
response like
[image]

Comment: *"...And I want to add request status checking, so I've started like this..."* Why so complex?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're falling prey to the [explicit `Promise` creation antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). You don't need `new Promise` in that code at all, and to add the status check, simply do it in a `then` handler:

```
return fetch(uri, { method, headers, body: JSON.stringify(data) })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            return response.json()
                .catch(() => {
                    // Couldn't parse the JSON
                    throw new Error(response.status);
                })
                .then(({message}) => {
                    // Got valid JSON with error response, use it
                    throw new Error(message || response.status);
                });
        }
        // Successful response, parse the JSON and return the data
        return response.json();
    });
```

Now:

- If an error is returned with valid JSON body, we try to use `message` from the parsed JSON as the error (rejection), falling back on `response.status` if there isn't one.
- If an error is returned by the body isn't valid JSON, we use `response.status` as the error (rejection)
- If a success is returned, we return the result of parsing it

Comment: but I need message inside data

Comment: @DmitriPortenko - I missed that. Simply add another `then` handler. I've updated the answer.

Comment: as I can see it will throw first error, but not second. Simply I want to have response.ok on second then

Comment: @DmitriPortenko - Why would you want that? If the request has failed, you want a failure, right? The second `then`'s handler will not be called with the code above if `response.ok` is falsy -- which is what you want.

Comment: Because I need error message on failure, I've added response result picture to my question.

Comment: so I want check `ok` and `message` at same time

Comment: @DmitriPortenko - I get it now. I'll update the answer. The key here is that even when `response.ok` is falsy, you're still getting back valid JSON.

Comment: @DmitriPortenko - Updated now. Thanks for explaining what I was missing!

Comment: @t-j-crowder thanks, I'll check it later and back to you.

Comment: @t-j-crowder works as expected. Also thanks for antipattern note!

Answer (score -1):

to get ok on the second then you can use Promise.all instead

```
fetch(uri, { method, headers, body: JSON.stringify(data) })
        .then(response => {
          return Promise.all([response.json(),response])
        })
        .then(([responseData,response]) => {
          // handle data here
        })
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Simply I want to have response.ok on second then