# Convert string to object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, parsing, react-props

I'm receiving through props some data:

```
this.props.data = [
         {"game_id":4,"city":"Pyeongchang","year":2018},
         {"game_id":2,"city":"Rio de Janeiro","year":2016}
];
```

this is what is received and it can be sent to render and show it on the screen.

The problem is when I want to access inside of this array.

For example:

```
const firstObj = this.props.data[0];
console.log('firstObj: ', firstObj); // prints [
```

I was expecting to the the first object (`{"game_id":4,"city":"Pyeongchang","year":2018}`) but it took the first char from `this.props.data`.

So I was thinking that the data is not well formatted.

`console.log(typeof this.props.data); // -> string` - it returns string which is weird

So I tried to convert it with JSON.parse:

`const convertedData = JSON.parse(this.props.data);` -> but this throws an error:

**Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.**

Why is this happening and how can it be solved?

**UPDATE**

Data is coming from Node.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./db/ocs_athletes.db');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  db.serialize(function () {
    db.all(
      'SELECT g.game_id, g.city, g.year, ar.athlete_id, ar.gold, ar.silver, ar.bronze FROM(Game g join AthleteResult ar on g.game_id = ar.game_id) order by g.year desc',
      function (err, rows) {
        return res.send(rows);
      }
    );
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

and in React app it is received in App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Table from './components/Table';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { apiResponse: [] };
  }

  callAPI() {
    fetch('http://localhost:9000/testAPI')
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((res) => this.setState({ apiResponse: res }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.callAPI();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <header className='App-header'>
          <Table data={this.state.apiResponse} />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

From here it is send through props to Table component:

```
class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    console.log('data: ', data); // prints the whole data

    console.log(typeof data); // prints string

    const convertData = JSON.parse(this.props.data); // throws the error I talked about


    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>{data}</tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218008/discussion-on-question-by-leo-messi-convert-string-to-object-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to convert your data to JSON when first receiving the response from the API? maybe you can try this

```
fetch(reqUrl, request)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        // your json result is here
    })
    .catch((error) => {

    })
```

Comment: This is right, OP is using `resp.text()` which returns the body as a string instead of the JSON. Also, OP should [check if the response is valid before parsing it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51811598/1218980).

Answer (score -1):

you should invoke `this.callAPI` in `componentDidMount`, not `componentWillMount`. Also, it would probably be simpler to initialize `this.state.apiResponse` as an empty array rather than a string so you don't have to convert it to a string and then back to an object with `JSON.parse`

Comment: yeah looks like the root of the problem was using `response.text` instead of `response.json`. Nonetheless, in a class component you should make api calls in `componentDidMount`, not `componentWillMount` :)